# How does correlated query with no aliases work?

Tags: sql, oracle

The below code returns outcome with no errors in the process. However, the variable `b` is not present in the view `nob`.

```
WITH basetbl AS (
    SELECT
        1 AS a,
        2 AS b,
        1 AS c
    FROM
        dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        2 AS a,
        3 AS b,
        0 AS c
    FROM
        dual
),nob AS (
    SELECT a, c
    FROM basetbl
) 
SELECT *
FROM basetbl
WHERE b IN (SELECT b FROM nob WHERE c = 1);
```

Returns:

```
"A"  "B"  "C"                           
 1    2    1                           
 2    3    0
```

Comment: Yes. Tested on Oracle Database 11g

Comment: This is how the SQL standard defines the visibility of column names. If a column name in a sub-query is not available, the column from the outer query is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT *
FROM basetbl
WHERE b IN (SELECT b FROM nob WHERE c = 1);
```

First, you should *always* qualify column names, so the query should look more like this:

```
SELECT bt.*
FROM basetbl bt
WHERE bt.b IN (SELECT n.b FROM nob n WHERE n.c = 1);
```

Then you would get an error.

Instead, Oracle applies its default scoping rules (which are similar to the scoping rules for all SQL databases).  So, when it doesn't find `b` in `nob`, it looks in the outer query.  The query is interpreted as:

```
SELECT bt.*
FROM basetbl bt
WHERE bt.b IN (SELECT bt.b FROM nob n WHERE n.c = 1);
```

Comment: This is not specific to Oracle, this is how the SQL standard defines the visibility rules. At least Postgres and SQL Server work exactly the same way.